# Track bookmarking event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarks

Any idea on how can I track users bookmarking event? I want to find out how many users are saving a specific page into their bookmarks, and every time this happens I want to call a callback function (i.e. AJAX) to store this data.

For what I know of JS this is not possible: I can initiate a bookmark creation, but this is not what I'm trying to do...

Even a jQuery plugin is ok. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not possible with JS then it's not possible with jQuery. (And as a user I hope it isn't possible.)

Comment: Well, thanks. I knew that, but I'm not working with bookmarking since 1998 (times of popups & popunder) I wanted a confirmation :)

Comment: Firefox has some functionality for this, but that may be the only one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/onCreated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. Bookmark creation is outside a web page's control.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder, How CodeProject articles are showing the Bookmark Count then?

(See the 'About Article' panel @ right side for the Bookmark count)
for example see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50411/Simple-6-Steps-to-Run-your-First-Azure-Worker-Role) one

Comment: ah looks like they are using there own Bookmark button, see that Star next to the print icon, and that's how it's tracked